# How to extract the first element from a : separated String in ANT

Tags: string, ant

I need to extract the tokens separated by ':' from the string `./src:./.apt_generated:` and get the individual tokens as list elements.  I tried using the concept in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349959/how-do-i-extract-the-1st-element-from-a-ant-csv-property) example as below ( tried some variations using dirsep, filesep etc. ).  None of those worked.  How can I get the desired list from the given string in ANT? I cannot use ant-contib or any other ant libraries.  I need to use only core ANT.

```
    <pathconvert property="dir.1" >
        <path path="${srcdir.list}"/>
        <chainedmapper>
            <flattenmapper/>
            <mapper type="regexp" from="(.*?):.*" to="\1"/>
        </chainedmapper>
    </pathconvert>

    <echo>dir.1 is ${dir.1}</echo>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use script task

```
<project name="proj">
  <property name="dir.list" value="./src:./.apt_generated:"/>

    <script language="javascript"> <![CDATA[
       var values = proj.getProperty("dir.list").split(":");
       proj.setProperty("dir.1", values[0]);
       proj.setProperty("dir.2", values[1]);
    ]]></script>

    <echo message="${dir.1}" />
    <echo message="${dir.2}" />
</project>
```

EDIT. I cannot tell exactly why the mapper doesn't work. I think it's not just a simple regex replace but it has some logic for path processing.

Try the following

```
<project name="proj">
   <pathconvert property="dir.1" >
     <path path="./src:./.apt_generated:"/>
      <chainedmapper>
         <flattenmapper/>
         <identitymapper/>
      </chainedmapper>
    </pathconvert>

   <echo>dir.1 is ${dir.1}</echo>
</project>
```

You see that it removed some characters from the string even if it was identity mapper.

Comment: Just so that I can learn ANT better, can you tell me why the above did not work which is the exact logic from the link I have in the question?